# file_put_contents (more than 1 file)

Tags: php, html, fopen

**Current code:**

```
public function downloadInvoicesFromServer($invoices=array())
{
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice)
    {
        if ($stream = fopen($invoice, 'r')) 
        {
            file_put_contents(PATH . '/invoices/' . rand() . '.pdf', $stream);
            fclose($stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Included are 3 files. PHP returns me those 3 included files, but only the last file with content. The first 2 files are empty.

I've got no clue what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone could help me?

**End result**:
2 (or more) files are uploaded on my server and are sent as attachments (with original content, of course) in an e-mail.

**Issue:**
Only the last file has its original content. All other files its content (no matter how many files) are empty.

Comment: `file_put_contents` writes from strings, not from file handles. Why not use `copy()`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
If data is a stream resource, the remaining buffer of that stream will be copied to the specified file. This is similar with using stream_copy_to_stream().

Comment: trim() function worked. Thanks all for your reply! The actual code worked, but it seems PHP_EOL explode (shift enter in text area) needs a trim().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trim() function worked. Thanks all for your reply! The actual code worked, but it seems PHP_EOL explode (shift enter in text area) needs a trim().